# Why is windows 7 firewall not blocking a program?

Tags: windows-7, firewall

I'd like to know how to properly block a program to access to the internet using the windows firewall. As a test I've tried to block google chrome or gpu-z but I haven't been successful, here's the steps I've followed (as an example I'll post my attempt to block google chrome):

- Windows firewall overview:

[image: overview]

- Disabled existing chrome inbound rules and created custom one:

[image: overview]

- Created chrome outbound rule:

[image: overview]

So, what am I missing here? Or more generally, what'd be the proper way to block a program to access the internet on windows?

The above is just one of the many frustrated attempts to apply the tips from these DIY on the internet :/

Comment: Chrome has several exe's that go out to the internet, what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Nothing specifically... I'm trying to learn how to block the internet access of any kind of program, chrome is the one I've picked up to learn more about the general process. Thing is, I've created rules blocking out directly tcp at 80/443 and that worked (as a test to check firewall works). Unfortunately, when I create specific rules for chrome as posted in the thread it won't work. For this [guy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wSIqC5pJy1A) is working though... So, what could be the reason is not working for me? What should I be checking?